# Runtime determination of object type

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I am programming in C#. I have an abstract class (Animal) and two derived classes (Dog and Cat) that inherits from Animal. I further have a static method called "Value" that works on Dog and on Cat. However, my user might call this method passing an Animal.

How can I determine if it is a Dog or a Cat? 
Can I "tag" the classes somehow? 
Please let me know if my design is wrong, and if I am doing something that I should not do.

Here is some sample code. The last function below (Value(Animal animal)) is the function I am unsure of.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public readonly string Name;
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(string name, double weight)
        : base(name)
    {
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public readonly double Weight;
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name, bool old)
        : base(name)
    {
        Old = old;
    }

    public readonly bool Old;
}

public class AnimalValuation
{
    public static double Value(Dog dog)
    {
        return dog.Weight;
    }

    public static double Value(Cat cat)
    {
        if (cat.Old == true)
        {
            return 100.0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

    public static double Value(Animal animal)
    {
        // if animal is Dog then do something like:
            Dog dog = (Dog)animal;
            return Value(dog);
        // if animal is Cat then do something like:
            Cat cat = (Cat)animal;
            return Value(cat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. if(animal is Dog) { // Do your stuff }else if(animal is Cat) { // cat processing } else { /I dont know }

Comment: `x is y` is correct.  However, it's arguable that a method taking an `Animal` as an argument shouldn't care what sub-type it is, and shouldn't need to do internal casting etc, instead it should just work against the methods/properties of the base class.

Answer (score 2):

The operator for that is actually `is`:

```
public static double Value(Animal animal)
{
    if (animal is Dog) {
        Dog dog = (Dog)animal;
        return Value(dog);
    }
    if (animal is Cat) {
        Cat cat = (Cat)animal;
        return Value(cat);
    }
}
```

Another approach to do this would be to put the value calculation in each implementation using an abstract (virtual) method:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    public Animal(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public readonly string Name;

    public abstract double Value();

}

public class Dog : Animal {

    public Dog(string name, double weight) : base(name) {
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public readonly double Weight;

    public override double Value() {
        return dog.Weight;
    }

}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name, bool old) : base(name) {
        Old = old;
    }

    public readonly bool Old;

    public override double Value() {
        if (Old) {
            return 100.0;
        } else {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you don't need a valuation helper class, you can just use:

```
double value = someAnimal.Value();
```

This approach forces you to implement the `Value` method for any new animal class that you create, so you don't risk forgetting to put it in the valuation helper. Also, anyone can implement a new animal without the need to be able to change the valuation helper.

Comment: I still prefer my answer. Property > Method. But it's just my opinion! :D

Comment: Instead of `is` + cast one could also use `as` + null check. Example: `Dog dog = animal as Dog; if (dog != null) { return Value(dog); }`. The difference is usually not noticable.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Yes, using a property instead of a method is a nice alternative. The choise is generally up to how advanced the calculation is; whether it's just a value that exists or if there is some heavy lifting required to get the value.

Comment: @Guffa Yeah, absolutely :) Thanks for answering the comment

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This design makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're approach is someway correct but I believe that you should use polymorphism here instead of a static `Value` method overloading.

So... why don't you declare an abstract  `Value` property in `Animal` and then you just access `Value` independently of actual concrete type of `Animal` (i.e. `Dog` or `Cat`)?

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public readonly string Name;

    public abstract double Value { get; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(string name, double weight)
        : base(name)
    {
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public readonly double Weight;

    public override double Value { get { return Weight; } }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(string name, bool old)
        : base(name)
    {
        Old = old;
    }

    public readonly bool Old;

    public override double Value { get { return Old ? 0 : 100; } }
}
```

And now it's so easy. Either if an `Animal`-derived class object reference is typed as its derived class or not, you can access `Value` and you'll get the right and expected value without statics:

```
Dog dog = new Dog("Bobby", 30);
Cat cat = new Cat("Kitty", false);

// We upcast Dog and Cat to Animal, but Value implementation
// is defined by the derived class, so even if you access
// Value from an Animal-typed reference, the Value will be
// the expected one for cats and dogs :)
Animal a1 = dog;
Animal a2 = cat;

double a1Value = a1.Value;
double A2Value = a2.Value;
```

### Note

As @DarrenYoung has said in some comment, *magic numbers are a bad idea*. Since `Dog.Value` is the weight and `Cat.Value` is who knows what (0 or 100...), this can led to confusion and code using references typed as `Animal` won't be able to know what `Animal.Value` refers to...

BTW, I just wanted to provide an approach in terms of software architecture and, with the lack of more info from the OP, I feel that we can't dive into the actual meaning of `Value`.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Does it matter? This is the good point about polymorphism and inheritance. You know what value is because of the actual type!!!

Comment: Typo. You probably meant `return Old ? 100 : 0;`.

Comment: @DarrenYoung You got crazy. I've just refactored initial OP code! I know 100 or 0 is a bad idea, but I just refactored OP code to use polymorphism...

Comment: @DarrenYoung BTW see the other answerer... It has provided almost the same approach but it uses a method instead of a read-only property.... I mean, it's a valid approach (the other and mine), and we could discuss if the OP code was good or not... but I believe that OP is looking for architecture rather than what actual code does...

Comment: @DarrenYoung In the other hand, the static method overloading approach has the same issue of "50 classes that inherit from Animal" with the extra work of having to implement 50 static methods. In addition, the meaning of Value is unknown for us, who knows what OP has inside his/her head....

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written is the (or at least 'a') correct way to determine the most derived type of a given object.

*However*, I would suggest the design of your code could use a bit of attention. I dont know what role the 'Value' method is playing in your production application, but it looks to me like it should be member of the `Animal` type, and overridden by `Dog`, `Cat` etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(animal.GetType() == typeof(Dog))
```

or

```
if(animal is Dog)
```

Comment: `GetType()` won't give the expected result if the OP then goes on to have `Poodle`, `Labrador`, etc.